# Creating interface for Editing ArcSDE Layers in web service online

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, web-service, versioning

The initial idea is to make a multiuser web service for editing versions of an ArcSDE geodatabase online (each version for each user).

Can I create my own personal interface with specífic tools of ArcGIS?

I need to edit 3D vertices of lines, polygons, points, create new features, copy, paste, clip, delete, make selections,... and other simple tools, also edit the attribute tables like in ArcGIS Desktop (but not geoprocessing tools), and I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely possible. You can start by taking a look at the ArcGIS Server [feature services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_feature_service/0154000002w8000000/). They provide functionality for performing web editing of the features stored in the ArcSDE geodatabase (both versioned and non-versioned editing is supported). You will be able to update the geometry and attributes of the features. 3D-editing is not directly enabled (not in the view you see data in ArcScene) yet editing data with the [z-values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Editing_features_with_z_values_in_feature_services/015400000288000000/) is absolutely possible.

You would need to either develop an own web application that would consume this feature service or use a ready-to-use application, for instance, [ArcGIS Viewer for Flex](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-viewer/) or [ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/silverlight-viewer/). Both of these viewers would be a great place for you to start testing the web editing functionality and they have built-in support for user log-in menus when accessing secured services. Specifying what ArcSDE version to connect would be possible both at the service level or directly in the code, I've seen some sample demos for that.

Most of the editing tools you named in the question are included with the viewers, but you would need to implement them on your own if you choose to build an own application. For those simple editing operations, you may use the geometry service - see here for full list of supported [geometry service operations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/). If there is something more advanced - [geoprocessing services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_geoprocessing_service/0154000004v5000000/) can be used.