# Steps for creating an online webmap with editable features using ArcGIS Server/SDE and SQL Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, enterprise-geodatabase

EDIT/UPDATE: I'm adding a bounty to this in hopes of obtaining a step-by-step guide to creating an online map with **feature editing** using the ArcGIS Flex API, SQL Server **Express** and ArcGIS Server 10.1. I've run into so many issues (database authentication with Express, [errors enabling feature editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57290/arcgis-server-error-feature-service-requires-a-registered-database)) that I think my best bet is to start over and go through each step. A moderately detailed guide would be very much appreciated.

---

I'm primarily a desktop GIS programmer and need to develop a web application in which features can be edited by multiple users. I'm looking for a brief summary of the full steps I would need to carry this process out if I were starting from scratch.

Software: ArcGIS Flex API and SQL Server Express with ArcGIS Server 10.1.

The steps as I understand them so far:

1) Install ArcGIS Server on our server (actually a virtual machine on an existing server)

2) Install the ArcGIS Web Adapter

3) Install ArcSDE on the same server

4) Install SQL Server Express on the same server

This is where I need some clarification. As I understand it I need to create a new geodatabase to store the features I wish to display/edit. I also understand I need to create a Feature Service and Geometry Service. Finally I will need to host the developed application using a web server.

I'm essentially looking for a walk-through for this process as I have never carried it out before. Any information/resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here, I've recently answered a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54564/steps-to-create-an-interface-editing-arcsde-layers-in-a-web-service-online-simi/55193#55193

Comment: Thanks @Alex - I came across this in my search. I have the basics covered, but I am new to ArcSDE so I need some direction as to creating a geodatabase on my server, storing features in it, and then accessing it with a Feature Service and Geometry Service that I need to setup from another (desktop) machine since I don't have ArcGIS Desktop on the server.

Comment: Then look here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005mm000000 :)

Comment: Just a couple of things to help you get started: you don't need a web adaptor (unless you want to access the services not via the port 6080). In 10.1, you don't have to install ArcSDE any longer - all the logic is already implemented in the ArcGIS Desktop. You would need to run a GP tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000162000000 to create a geodb in SQL Server. If using the Express version, you work with Database Servers connection, not the SDE-type geodatabase.

Comment: Another great step-by-step tutorial on building a web editing application: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/cloudGIS/print/book/export/html/31, they use ArcGIS Viewer for Flex. Could also be relevant for you!

Comment: Let me get this straight. You are going to make a web application with a short list of business requirements (web editing, database storage), and you are specifying as a development requirement relatively complex, expensive, 3rd party applications with no knowledge of how they work? Why would you do that? Break this problem up into simple pieces and work with a web developer. The simpler the solution using standard web practices will make this easier. At the very least choose a simple path: javascript+openlayers and a database, OR use arcgisonline / giscloud. Flex? really?

Comment: @westyvw You know, he just just may be stuck in ESRI ecosystem like some of us other poor fools. :/

Comment: OUt of interest, are you using Express because its free?  If so, perhaps look at using postgresSQL with ArcGIS for Server.

Comment: @Simon, editing other RDBMS is only supported at Enterprise editions.

Comment: We are stuck in the ESRI world and we already have the software - I just happen to be new-ish to the web GIS world and have found this process particularly frustrating. I have created similar/simple web maps using open source software, but the requirements for this particular project are different.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, as westyvs suggested, this is a lot to ask in one question; but I think I'll take it on for you. However, I need to gather some more information first:

1. What edition of ArcGIS server 10.1 do you own? I see you suggest that MSSQL Express will be your RDBMS, so that leads me to believe you'll be using AGS 10.1 Workgroup Edition. Please confirm.
2. The Web Adaptor needs to be installed on a Web Server; so far it sounds like you're in the Microsoft windows ecosystem so I'm going to infer that this will be IIS7 or IIS8, correct? Please confirm.
3. At 10.1 you do not need to install SDE (especially for what it sounds like you need to accomplish); it is integrated, which, they claim, is why the call it ArcGIS *for* Server 10.1
4. Suit yourself as to where you want to install MSSQL Express, but keep in mind Express' inherit database size, processor, and memory access limitations. Depending on how many users will be concurrently editing and how big your DB will be, it may be beneficial to address this as an install on another machine (if for nothing other than configuring a better storage option).
5. Do you need to deploy your services/application as secured? If not, we could explore other options/ways your users can consume these services and possible skip a few steps.

Your understanding of the general process is correct; there's just so many small configuration steps along the way to get each component communicating correctly.

I've deployed both personal, workgroup, and enterprise server/editing environments within the ESRI ecosystem/stack, so I'm quite certain I could get you set-up and running. However, there's a lot of small nuances to go over, so maybe we could schedule some time over in one of the chat rooms?? Please respond to the above questions, but feel free to PM me if you want to work out a chat time, ok?

MODERATOR/Anyone else: If this is better placed as a 'comment' please let me know and I will attempt to move it. However, I do feel I can answer all of the questions (via chat).

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply. To answer your questions: 1) ArcGIS 10.1 Enterprise, 2) IIS7, 3) I thought SDE was needed at 10.1 for feature editing?, 4) We have options on where to install (a couple servers), 5) Yes, secured.

Comment: 1) OK so using Enterprise, but do you have access to a SQL Standard license? The Enterprise + Express combo isn't going to be favorable (likely not doable either). 2)Ok 3) No, again its integrated and covered here quite well http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37125/arcsde-10-1-no-longer-needed 4) OK 5) OK secured, so this helps narrow the options.
Ok, well just get back to me regarding the Express-Enterprise thing so we can move this forward. Also, could you find a time to move this to the chat dialog?

Comment: We do have a SQL Standard license installed on one of our servers. Chat would work - 10AM PST/1PM EST tomorrow? Same time later this week if that doesn't work?

Comment: An FYI: I use an instance of sqlexpress 2008 r2 with Arc Server 10.0 and 10.1 Enterprise, and have no issues. I use direct connect.

Comment: right, you just won't be creating an enterprise GDB there ;)

Comment: @Clickinaway - I'm unsure if we're talking about the same thing... I use ArcDesktop 10.1's CreateEnterprise[GDB] tool to create and use a multi-user geodatabase on a SQL Expr 08 r2 server, used concurrently by about 10 people, daily, for the past X years. Works flawlessly. Yes, limited in size and memory usage - I've never come close to reaching those limits in my app. I also use SQL Standard.