# Feature Access ArcGIS 10.1 Registered Database Publishing Error

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-layer, error-00090

I created a feature class from an XY table in ArcCatalog, and I am trying to publish a feature access enabled map to my server.

When I try, I keep getting a 00090 error which is "feature service requires a registered database". I registered my database using server manager by creating a .sde file with a python script, and the table and shapefile are in my enterprise geodatabase (created and enabled with the tool in ArcGIS). The database validates on the server manager page.

I have an ArcGIS server (10.1 SP1) running on a Microsoft 2012 Datacenter Edition Server. I am using MSSQL 2012 enterprise editionand trying to publish with ArcMap 10.1.

I am very new to ArcGIS, so I may be forgetting/overlooking something silly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried [ArcGIS Server Error: "Feature service requires a registered database"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57290/arcgis-server-error-feature-service-requires-a-registered-database).

Answer (score 2):

If you're still working with the XY data as an "event layer" then you will not be able to publish it as a feature service for editing.

See the **[Make XY Event Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006z000000)** help where it says:

> is not possible to interactively move the output layer's points
>   through editing controls, since event layers are not editable.

You will have to copy the XY event layer into a new featureclass in your geodatabase.  If you've done this and still get the "Feature Service requires a registered geodatabase", then ensure that the connection to the data that is in your map document exactly matches the connection that you've registered in your geodatabase.